# How to ignore failed request and continue responsing to the next requests?

Tags: android, observable, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

I have a function that takes an article id list to set on the adapter. Everything works fine until at least one of the requests fails. Then the returned list is empty. How to make it ignore a failing request and move on to the next one? For example, I request 5 articles 1 fail, 4 are okay, so I get a list of 4.
I know, I need to use `onErrorResumeNext()` here, but I don't know-how.

Interface:

```
@GET("articles/{id}")
Observable<Articles> getArticle1(@Path("id") int id);
```

Activity:

```
private void getMoreArticles(List<Integer> l) {
    
        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClientRX().create(ApiInterface.class);

        List<Observable<?>> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int id : l) {
            requests.add(apiInterface.getArticle1(id));
        }

        Observable.zip(requests, new Function<Object[], List<Articles>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Articles> apply(@NonNull Object[] objects) {
                List<Articles> articlesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
               
                for (Object response : objects) {
                    articlesArrayList.add((Articles) response);
                }
            
                return articlesArrayList;
            }
        })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.<List<Articles>>empty())
                .subscribe(
                        new Consumer<List<Articles>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void accept(List<Articles> articlesList) {
                                adapter = new Adapter(articlesList, MainActivity.this);
                                if (fav) recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                else addRV().setAdapter(adapter);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                initListener();
                                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                            }
                        },
                        new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                            @Override
                            public void accept(Throwable e) throws Exception {

                            }
                        }
                ).isDisposed();
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify your use case a bit but I hope you got my point. You need to somehow "signal" that there was some problem in your API call and this specific `Articles` object should be skipped in your `.zip()` operator's zipper function. You can for example wrap the return value into `Optional`. When the value is preset, it indicates everything went fine. If not, the API call failed.

```java
class SO69737581 {

    private Observable<Articles> getArticle1(int id) {
        return Observable.just(new Articles(id))
                .map(articles -> {
                    if (articles.id == 2) { // 1.
                        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid id");
                    } else {
                        return articles;
                    }
                });
    }

    Observable<List<Articles>> getMoreArticles(List<Integer> ids) {
        List<Observable<Optional<Articles>>> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int id : ids) {
            Observable<Optional<Articles>> articleRequest = getArticle1(id)
                    .map(article -> Optional.of(article)) // 2.
                    .onErrorReturnItem(Optional.empty()); // 3.

            requests.add(articleRequest);
        }

        return Observable.zip(requests, objects -> {
            List<Articles> articlesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Object response : objects) {
                Optional<Articles> optionalArticles = (Optional<Articles>) response;
                optionalArticles.ifPresent(articlesArrayList::add); // 4.
            }

            return articlesArrayList;
        });
    }
}
```

Explanation of interesting parts:

1. Simulate API error with id = 2
2. Wrap result of API the call into optional
3. Return empty optional when an error occurs
4. Add articles value into result array if the value is present

Verification:

```java
public class SO69737581Test {

    @Test
    public void failedArticleCallsShouldBeSkipped() {
        SO69737581 tested = new SO69737581();

        TestObserver<List<Articles>> testSubscriber = tested
                .getMoreArticles(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4))
                .test();

        List<Articles> result = Arrays.asList(
                new Articles(1),
                new Articles(3),
                new Articles(4)
        );

        testSubscriber.assertComplete();
        testSubscriber.assertValue(result);
    }
}
```

For sake of completeness, this is how I defined `Article` class:

```java
class Articles {

    public int id;

    public Articles(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Articles articles = (Articles) o;
        return id == articles.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```